# How to kill Appium sessions on Appium server

Tags: selenium, webdriver, appium, appium-ios

When I trying to start an appium driver in the start of test it gives me error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be     created. Details: Problem getting session data for driver type AndroidDriver; does     it implement 'get driverData'? (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace     information)
```

This happenes when the previous tests didn't closed or failed properly and haven't sent driver.quit() to appium server. So there is a hanged session on appium server I need to kill. There is timeout option to kill when there is no action, but it's not that efficient in my cases.

I'm thinking about to kill the session after checking the server, if there is another one while starting a session. Any idea? I saw this error on internet but couldn't find a proper answer actually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using TestNG, in your @AfterSuite write `driver.quit()` / `closeApp()` or close node.exe. Killing node.exe process will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already doing that but in case of that code is not worked (internet is broken for example, or when stopping the test manually in the middle), I need to clear session on appium server while starting of a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It seems that it was an appium bug for v1.5. After updating to 1.5.3 (yesterday's release) --session-override is working now.